# Children calling grandparent function

Tags: reactjs.net

I have a box containing a list. The list is made of todoItems. A delete button is next to each item. The button should call the delete method of the box class. Should I pass it to the class List first? Can I call directly the method in the class Box?

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick(e)
    {
        const todoItemId = this.props.todoItemId;
        if (!todoItemId)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.props.onTodoItemDeleteList({ todoItemId: todoItemId });   
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="todoItem">
                <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>delete</button>;
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My List: here the onTodoItemDeleteList is seen in the console, but appears as undefined.

```
class TodoItemList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleItemDeleteList = this.handleItemDeleteList.bind(this);
    }
    handleItemDeleteList(todoItemId)
    {
        //call handleItemDelete
    }
    render() {
        if (this.props.data)
        {
          var todoItemNodes = this.props.data.map(function (todoItem){
              return (
                <TodoItem todoItemId={todoItem.todoItemId} onTodoItemDeleteList={this.handleItemDeleteList}  key={todoItem.todoItemId}>
                </TodoItem>
              );
          });
        }
        return <div className="todoItemList">{todoItemNodes}</div>;
    }
}
```

My Box: this is where I handle my ajax call to the server.

```
class TodoItemBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: [] };
        this.handleItemDelete = this.handleItemDelete.bind(this);
    }
    handleItemDelete(todoItemId) {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('todoItemId', todoItemId);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', this.props.deleteUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = () => this.loadTodoItemsFromServer();
        xhr.send(data);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="todoItemBox">
                <TodoItemList data={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using arrow function in the parent too, it looks like this:

```
onTodoItemDeleteList={ (todoItemId) => handleItemDeleteList(todoItemId)}
```

and in the constructor:

```
handleItemDeleteList = this.handleItemDeleteList.bind(this);
```